# php file_get_contents encoding issue of showing corrupted text

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, file-get-contents

I do have html files created in same server . I need to read html file content as text and I used file_get_contents() function for that. When I did so, it was returning corrupted text, similar to symbols we see with an encoding issue. When I opened the html file in text editor, it was fine with regular characters. I have [linked](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y2iya9epd73c0r1/9663testme.docx.html?dl=0) https://www.dropbox.com/s/y2iya9epd73c0r1/9663testme.docx.html?dl=0 a test HTML file which file_get_contents fails to read/show properly.

I did use following function to convert read content to UTF-8, but still sometimes it gives corrupted text though there is some progress.

```
 function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) { 
  $content = file_get_contents($fn); 
  return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', 
  mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true)); 
}
```

I do appreciate if someone can guide me to find a solution to resolve this issue with file_get_contents or any other alternative solution.

Thank you.

Comment: The issue will be because your HAVE to ENCODE and DECODE the file with the same type. So for instance if you create a file in ASCII and try to convert it to UTF-8, it most likely wont give you good characters.Try making a new file and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks @Twister1002 for your prompt reply. Actually these HTML files are created using phpword, original word files can be with any encoding. Created HTML files contain UTF-8 in meta. When I open HTML file in FTP's editor I can actual content. But its different when read with file_get_contents

Comment: Eh, that was my issue when I dealt with it, so I figured I'd say it.

Comment: Yes, this can be a similar issue.  I couldnt find a way to directly extract text from a word file, so I m saving word file as html with phpword.  I checked phpword classes couldnt find in which encoding it writes the file. Meta tags in HTML contains UTF-8 as text content encoding.

Comment: Have you tried leaving out 'UTF-8'  just to see if it automatically finds the encoding?

Comment: Initially it was like that, and results were worst.

Answer (score 0):

call using file_get_contents_utf8('9663testme.docx.html');

```
function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) { 
  //$content = file_get_contents($fn); 
  //return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', 
  //mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true)); 
  echo file_get_contents($fn);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.Both file_get_contents and above function were tried. Wtih file_get_contents_utf8() results are better but even that fails sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

This great little library helped me to solve the issue.

[ForceUTF8 https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8)